# How can I improve the typing of this partially applied function?

Tags: typescript

I have these filtering/pagination variables:

```
export interface FilterVariables {
  chartId?: string | null;
  screenId?: string | null;
  first?: number | null;
   ...
}
```

I have a number of handlers I need to create for controls to mutate these variables:

```
const handleSetChartId = (chartId: string) => {
    setFilters((current) => ({
      ...current,
      chartId,
    }));
  };

const handleSetFirst = (first: number) => {
    setFilters((current) => ({
      ...current,
      first,
    }));
  };
```

It would be convenient to partially apply the filter type and create a more generic function that would generate my handlers:

```
const handleSetFilter = (filter: keyof FilterVariables) => (
    value: FilterVariables[typeof filter],
  ) => {
    setFilters((current) => ({
      ...current,
      filter: value,
    }));
  };
```

This works, but `value` is typed to `string | number | null | undefined` - is there any way to better constrain `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a combination of generics and NonNullable utility type, you can write:

```ts
const handleSetFilter = <K extends keyof FilterVariables>(filter: K) => 
  (value: NonNullable<FilterVariables[K]>) => {
  setFilters((current) => ({
    ...current,
    filter: value,
  }));
};

const setChartId = handleSetFilter('chartId')
// inferred to const setChartId: (value: string) => void
```

Alternatively, you can create only one function taking an object with any subset of filters, instead of generating separate handlers:

```ts
const handleFilterUpdate = (f: Partial<FilterVariables>) => {
  setFilters((current) => ({
      ...current,
      ...f,
    }));
}

handleFilterUpdate({chartId: '1212'})
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of a generic to "store" which key was used in the call, then use it in the returned function to get the correct type:

```
function handleSetFilter<
    K extends keyof FilterVariables
>(filter: K): (value: FilterVariables[K]) => unknown { ... }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADaSgNTlYOAIwwgGdkBvAWAChlkEALfMASQBMB+ALmTLAEQAc2QAfZCACuGDAG46DMgigQIITr36DQoidNkL6yGMCgCt0gLZFo4yTPl0AvnTocICDPhQwpIBDBgAHsQZBYQDlIAZQgwdCxoAB4AaWQIAA9ISIoAawgAT2CYNExsPAJiUjIAPgAKU0SoPhSASj46gDc4DCkIPgTy-EIScgBtFIBdVuQAXhrkf1yQYIB3ECM6CKiIWPiy6DqAImZWTiPW44ujbZi4wcOj5VV1c8uj6624SLv9puPTOYwBc6gAGVpGIA)